# TS how can I this function write to a arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

How can I write this generic function with a arrow function ?

```
function simpleState<T>(initial: T): [() => T, (v: T) => void] {
  let value: T = initial;
  return [
    () => value,
    (v: T) => {
      value = v;
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const simpleState = <T>(initial: T): [() => T, (v: T) => void] => {
  // same function body as before
}
```

Since you tagged react-native, be aware that in a `.tsx` file, this will probably not work, since the `<T>` will be parsed as being a JSX tag. You can either put it in a `.ts` file, and import it into a `.tsx` file, or use one of the following workarounds to get it to not be interpreted as a JSX element.

Trailing comma:

```
<T,>(initial: T): // etc
```

Extend from unknown:

```
<T extends unknown>(initial: T): // etc
```

Comment: Type parameter declarations allow trailing commas so you can write `<T,>(initial: T): ...` and that will fix any parsing problems in tsx files.  You could also do `<T extends unknown>(initial: T): ...` .

Comment: @jcalz thanks, i did not know that

Answer (score 0):

```
const simpleState2 = <T>(initial: T): [() => T, (v: T) => void] => {
  let value: T = initial;
  return [
    () => value,
    (v: T) => {
      value = v;
    },
  ];
}
```

Comment: the answer is the same as the accepted answer. I would recommend deleting this answer.